# Show positive second order derivetive in the range

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functions, optimization

I have the log-ellipsoid function defined as:
$$f(x)=\log(1+\epsilon x^2), \epsilon=10^{4}$$
And then I have found the gradient as:
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{2 \epsilon x}{\epsilon x^2 +1}$$
And the hessian is found to:
$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x)}{\partial^2 x}=\frac{2 \epsilon }{\epsilon x^2 +1}-\frac{4\epsilon^2x^2}{(\epsilon x^2+1)^2}$$
And now I have to show that we have a positive Hessian in the range $|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. How can I do that and what is mean by showing only positivity for the hessian in the range?

Answer (score 1):

Positivity of $\frac{ \partial^2 f}{ \partial^2 x}(x)$ for $|x| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ is equivalent to
$$
\frac{4 \epsilon^2 x^2}{(\epsilon x^2 + 1)^2} < \frac{2 \epsilon}{\epsilon x^2 + 1}
$$
for all $|x| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$. Since
$$
\frac{4 \epsilon^2 x^2}{(\epsilon x^2 + 1)^2} = \left( \frac{2 \epsilon}{\epsilon x^2 + 1} \right)^2 x^2
$$
it suffices to show that
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{2 \epsilon}{\epsilon x^2 + 1} x^2 &< 1, \\
2 \epsilon x^2 &< \epsilon x^2 + 1, \\
\epsilon x^2 &< 1, \\
\end{align*}
$$
which is true when $|x| < \frac{1}{ \sqrt{\epsilon}}$.